# Put tab bar to all the viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've created a Tabbar with `UIView` what I want is to put this tab bar view on every storyboard this tabbar transfers to.

I tried connecting all the tab bar elements to a button code below and open the storyboard, but the tab bar doesn't show up. any solutions ?

```swift
    @IBAction func tabBarClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Saved", bundle: nil)
        print(sender.tag)
        if sender.tag == 3 {
            guard let savedView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SavedViewController") as? SavedViewController else {
                return
            }
            contentView.addSubview(savedView.view)
            savedView.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not using UITabbarController?

Comment: There is only way to do that: use UITabbarViewController on the top of your view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your custom tabbar, the only way to achieve the expected behavior is to create a custom container view controller and put child controllers in it. You can read more about create container controllers [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller)